# Help understand the facrtorization theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I am reading the following proof about factorization theorem but I have trouble understanding the highlighted part.

> [image]
>   [image]

Related lemma:

> [image]

Comment: Unrelated, but just  curious. Which book is this?

Comment: @LandonCarter This is Mathematical Statistics second edition by Jun Shao.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highlighted equality follows form the first sentence of the proof, i.e. for any $A\in \mathcal{B}^n$, $P(A\mid T)$ does not depend on $P$. It means that $P_j(A\mid T)=m(T)$ $(P_j-a.s.)$ for some measurable function $m$ independent of $j$ and for any $B\in \sigma(T)$,
$$
\int_{B}1_AdP_j=\int_B m(T)dP_j
$$
by the definition of conditional expectations. Now, for a given $P\in\mathcal{P}$, replace $m(T)$ with $P(A\mid T)$. However, this notation is awkward. It is better to keep $m(T)$ in all parts of this proof, i.e. the highlighted part implies that $Q(A\mid T)=m(T)$ $(Q-a.s.)$. Then
$$
P(A)=\int m(T)dP=\int Q(A\mid T)\frac{dP}{dQ}dQ \quad\dots
$$
and so on.